# How to get the parameters of url in Crystal lang

Tags: url, parameters, get, crystal-reports

I'm learning Crystal lang for web development. I don't understand at all how to get the parameters that i send in a url. In PHP it is just $_GET[param] but all i find in crystal documentation is how to get the elements from the url but not how to get this url. I spent many hours in this but don't understand at all. Does anyone know how to do ? I'm sure it is not difficult but i don't find ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default http server then you can acccess it using [query_param](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.32.1/HTTP/Request.html#query_params-instance-method)

like this -

```
server = HTTP::Server.new do |context|
   context.request.query_params.each do |name, value|
       puts "query key is #{name} & value is #{value}"
   end
end
```

but if you want to use it in a simple way - you can use some framework like [shivneri](https://shivneriforcrystal.com/)

Here is how to do it in shivneri

```
class UserController < Shivneri::Controller

    @[Worker]
    def add_user

        user_id = query["userid"]?

        return text_result("ok")

    end
end
```

For more info about - query string in shivneri framework, please visit - https://shivneriforcrystal.com/tutorial/query/